# Chrome causing hyperdrive on A8-7410 processor

Tags: google-chrome, dell, inspiron, amd-processor

[cpu usage during and after using chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzZVP.png)  Why is chrome causing one of my cores on my A8-7410 processor to run continuously @ 92-94% even when chrome is closed and all background activities disabled? Its a new dell inspiron i5555-428 laptop. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.3 but it only happens in Ubuntu. It doesn't happen in windows 10. Any Ideas, Thanks